# Freemarker <compress> tag is trimming data inside ${} also

Tags: freemarker

I have code like this :

FTL:

```
<#compress>
${doc["root/uniqCode"]}
</#compress>
```

Input is XML Nodemodel
The xml element is having data like: ID_234   567_89   
When it is processed the out is: "ID_234 567_89"
The three white spaces between 234 and 567 is trimmed down to one white-space and lost all the white spaces at the end of the value.
I need the value as it is :"ID_234   567_89   "
When i removed the  tags it works as expected irrespective of newFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true).

Why should  tag trims data resulted from ${}?
Please help.

Comment: Well, this behavior is exactly as defined in [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_compress.html). If you need to preserve spaces in the **output** of your variable, don't use `compress`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If i don't use compress i see all the new lines and tabs, etc as part of result . my FTL block is huge with many ifs, elseifs , assigns, lists, etc... which has all indentation for each statement. What is the good approach to avoid indentation data but it should result in the exact out come of ${} which has white-spaces, as shown in my example. Do i need to write my own statemachine logic for this?

Comment: <#list subdoc["postEventTrade/swap/swapStream"] as swapStream>
      <#if tempiRefid = swapStream["payerPartyReference/@href"] &&
      swapStream["calculationPeriodAmount/calculation/notionalSchedule/notionalStepSchedule/currency"]?has_content>
      
       ${swapStream["calculationPeriodAmount/calculation/notionalSchedule/notionalStepSchedule/currency"]}
       
      <#elseif tempiRefid = swapStream["payerPartyReference/@href"] &&
      swapStream["calculationPeriodAmount/calculation/fxLinkedNotionalSchedule/varyingNotionalCurrency"]?has_content>

Answer (score 0):

You could simply replace the characters you don't want manually (in the following example tabs, carriage returns and newlines), e.g.

```
${doc["root/uniqCode"]?replace("[\\t\\r\\n]", "", "rm")}
```

See ?replace built-in for strings: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace

Comment: I removed `<#compress>` tag , and handling all FTL's  *CR,LF or \n* manually to solve my issue, since I need to preserve the empty spaces with in my variable's value.